# Access require controller in a directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
app.directive('mainCtrl', function () {
    return {
        controller: function () {
            this.funcA = function(){}
        }
    };
});

app.directive('addProduct', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^mainCtrl',
        link: function (scope, lElement, attrs, mainCtrl) {
            mainCtrl.funcA()
        }
    };
});
```

I don't want to use the link method but the controller method.
Is there a way to get the mainCtrl in the controller method of the directive addProduct.

something like:

```
app.directive('addProduct', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^mainCtrl',
        controller: function (scope, mainCtrl) {
            mainCtrl.funcA()
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: You could just make a standalone controller and add it to both directives

Comment: Has the answer below addressed your question?

Answer (score 4):

You'd still need to use the `link` function because the controllers are injected there. What you could, however, is request your directive's own controller and then set the other required controller as its property:

```
app.directive('addProduct', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['addProduct','^mainCtrl'],
        controller: function ($scope) {
            // this.mainCtrl is still not set here
            // this.mainCtrl.funcA(); // this will cause an error

            // but typically it is invoked in response to some event or function call
            $scope.doFuncA = function(){
               this.mainCtrl.funcA();
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls){
          var me = ctrls[0], mainCtrl = ctrls[1];
          me.mainCtrl = mainCtrl;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Or you can add it to the scope instead of requiring own controller.

Answer (score 1):

Since AngularJS 1.5, you can use the `$onInit` lifecycle hook of the controller. As written in the [documentation of `require`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-), when defining `require` as an object and setting `bindToController` to `true`, the required controllers are added to the controller as properties after the controller has been constructed, but before the `$onInit` method is run. So the code would look like this:

```js
app.directive('mainCtrl', function () {
    return {
        controller: function () {
            this.funcA = function(){}
        }
    };
});

app.directive('addProduct', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: {
            myParentController: '^mainCtrl'
        },
        bindToController: true,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            this.$onInit = function() {
                this.myParentController.funcA();
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
app.directive('mainCtrl', function () {
    return {
        controllerAs: 'main',
        controller: function () {
            this.funcA = function(){}
        }
    };
});

app.directive('addProduct', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^mainCtrl',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.main.funcA();
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: and what if I want using ngModelController

Comment: It does not work on angular directives but it a good solution for custom made directives

Answer (score 0):

Pass the controller to the scope on the link function then accessing the scope on controller. Like this:

```
app.directive('mainCtrl', function () {
       return {
            controller: function () {
                this.funcA = function(){}
            }
        };
    });

app.directive('addProduct', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^mainCtrl',
        link: function (scope, lElement, attrs, mainCtrl) {
            scope.ctrl=mainCtrl;
        },controller:function($scope){
            $scope.ctrl.funcA();
        }
    };
});
```